# Eloquent ORM "standalone" DB::raw fails

Tags: php, orm, eloquent

For a project I'm working on, I'm using the Eloquent ORM standalone, as explained on [this page](https://github.com/illuminate/database#illuminate-database). Everything is working fine, except that I can not use DB::raw in my code. I got the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DB' not found
```

That is correct, as I am only using Eloquent from the Laravel framework, not Laravel itself. Is it possible to use something like DB::raw so I can use specific SQL codes? For example `where(DB::raw('YEAR(DateField)'),2013)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, looking for a solution for ages, asked it on SO, and found an answer elsewhere on the internet.

`Model::whereRaw('YEAR(DateField) = 2013')` will do the trick.

edit:
If you want to use `DB::raw` in any other part (for example in the `select`, you can use the following:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression as raw;
// You can now use "new raw()" instead of DB::raw. For example:
$yourVar = YourModel::select(new raw("count(FieldA) AS FieldACount"),'FieldB')->groupBy('FieldB')->lists(new raw('FieldACount'),'FieldB');
```

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking how to wrap a self-made database seeder in a transaction.

The function for that is DB::transaction(function(){});

With that said, DB is a facade.  According to the [Laravel Facade Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades) DB references both DatabaseManager and Connection.

If you are using standalone Eloquent, you'll want to get the connection out of the Capsule object.  Code ends up looking something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$db = $capsule->getConnection();

$db->transaction(function()
{
  // your transaction code here
});
```

Comment: thank you @Kirkland , it's useful for me to use transaction in standalone Eloquent